# How to disable device font-size change for my Android app WebView fonts

Tags: android, webview

I have `WebView` in my `Android` app, if I change the device font-size to large then `WebView` fonts are also large.

I tried this solution but not worked:

```
webView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(1);
webView.getSettings().setMinimumLogicalFontSize(1);
```

Please let me know if any solution regarding this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have done this using this solution :

webView.getSettings().setTextZoom(100); // 100% is maximum here

May be it would be helpful for others too.

Comment: For what it's worth, using ionic, you must use the `mobile-accessibility` plugin. Setting text zoom to 100% also solves this issue. It can be called this way : `this.mobileAccessibility.setTextZoom(100);` . For more details, see : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/mobile-accessibility

Answer (score 0):

Try `setDefaultFixedFontSize(10);` or `setDefaultFontSize(10);`

the default size is 16.

Comment: It doesn't work for my case as i have web view.  But i have done it in another way , just posting the solution may be helpful to others.

Comment: the webView.getSettings() should return you a WebSettings Object and in this object the two methods a available.

Comment: see my answer below , its working in my case. and thanks for your help :-)